# OIDC with Keycloak and Django - Missing States

Tags: django, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm attempting to set up OIDC with Keycloak as my IdP and Django (using Django Rest Framework and mozilla-django-oidc) as my client server. I have got keycloak installed and a rough Django application stood up that successfully redirects to keycloak where I can then successfully authenticate (to keycloak), but when I'm redirected back to django I'm missing information, specifically `oidc_states`.

The redirect to django triggers this log entry:

```
[12/Oct/2021 08:28:06] "GET /api/oidc/callback/?state=QGsO26esqdtHZcsfRfYoXvUy0QWcGdZv&session_state=493887a4-600e-4dd2-aaaf-4134ea671c9a&code=dfe1573e-cf8e-4829-8874-a3500ba63712.493887a4-600e-4dd2-aaaf-4134ea671c9a.c1dfdb46-140c-4ccd-8308-6db3b468346a HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

This contains three keys: `state`, `session_state`, and `code`.

The default callback view provided by mozilla-django-oidc contains this:

```
    def get(self, request):
        """Callback handler for OIDC authorization code flow"""

        if request.GET.get('error'):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                auth.logout(request)
            assert not request.user.is_authenticated
        elif 'code' in request.GET and 'state' in request.GET:
            if 'oidc_states' not in request.session:
                return self.login_failure()
        # ...
```

Because keycloak isn't making the redirect with `oidc_states` added, this is immediately failing and I haven't been able to figure out why. I'm guessing that the problem is with my keycloak client configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To any wayward travelers, I wish you luck. Ultimately, I solved my problem by re-configuring my mozilla-django-oidc settings. Specifically, I was missing:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend", # default
    "mozilla_django_oidc.auth.OIDCAuthenticationBackend",
)
```

This allowed for my application to authenticate *both* with the existing flow and using the new OIDC flow. The call to `authenticate` in the OIDC callback view was failing because I didn't have this authentication backend specified, so it was trying to just use the default.